# Can electron jump from $n=2$ to $n=3$?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Assume Bohr's Model. Lets not consider latest modern theory.
Consider a Hydrogen atom in ground state (n=1). 
It excites to next level n=2. It will stay here for 10^-8 seconds.
Now we supply more energy.
It goes to level n=3.
But, will it wait for me in n=2 for a long time before I can arrange for more energy? Because the time of stay is very small 10^-8 seconds.

So does it mean we can transfer an electron from n=1 easily. But it is less likely that it will remain there for long time so that we can send it from n=2 to n=3?

Comment: Why do you write that the electron will stay in the state n=2 for $10^{-8}~s$?

Comment: Why use the Bohr model?

Comment: There are multiple states on for n=2 and n=3. Which transition are you interested in?

Comment: If the transition is caused by light absorption, what is the intensity, frequency and polarisation? If not what is causing the transition?

Comment: @my2cts : Good reasons to *not* use Bohr's Model...

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the atom will remain in the $n=2$ state for a few nanoseconds is correct for an isolated hydrogen atom.

However, consider some hydrogen gas that's in thermal equilibrium at some high temperature $T$.  Collisions between the hydrogen atoms then *also* contribute to electronic excitations.  The probability of finding an atom in a state with energy $E$ is proportional to the [Boltzmann factor](https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/phys/boltz.htm) $e^{-E/kT}$, where the constant is $k\approx\rm 25\,meV/300\,K$.  The $n=2$ state in hydrogen is about $\rm 10\,eV$ above the ground state, so at room temperature the probability of finding an atom in the excited state is tiny, like $10^{-100}$.  But at 3000K the probability has increased all the way up to $10^{-18}$, so every mole ($=10^{24}$ atoms) of atomic hydrogen gas at that temperature will have a few million atoms in the higher-energy state at any instant.

A practical application of this arises in solar spectroscopy.  The sun's [chromosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosphere) is a diffuse layer of very hot hydrogen above the sun's [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere). The photosphere emits blackbody light containing all frequencies / wavelengths / colors.  Because the chromosphere is hot and massive, it contains at any instant very many hydrogen atoms in the $n=2$ excited state.  Since the light from the photosphere must pass through the chromosphere on its way out of the Sun, the population of $n=2$ atoms in the chromosphere is available to absorb the [Balmer wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series), and a spectrum of light from the Sun's main disk is dark at those particular colors.  These dark spectral lines are experimental evidence of the population of $n=2$ atoms and can be seen with a [cheap spectrometer](https://www.flinnsci.com/project-star-student-spectrometer/ap6040/).

(What about the re-emission of the light, you ask? The excited hydrogen atoms can relax by re-emitting the Balmer light and returning to $n=2$, or by emitted a Lyman photon and returning to $n=1$, etc. But the direction of the re-emitted light is random.  During a solar eclipse the chromosphere is visible as a layer of pink just surrounding the sun. The pink comes from the $n=3\to 2$ transition.)